# Modify awk code to get only second instance of string in a file

Tags: unix, awk

I use the following one-liner to get the 4th column of all lines in my .out file containing the string "CHEESE", and then sort them in a .csv file.

```
awk '/CHEESE/{print $4}' ./*/*/*.out | pr -9s',' > ofile.csv
```

Each of my .out files has two instances of the string 'CHEESE' and I only wish to take the 4th column of the 2nd instance. How can I modify the above one-liner to only extract the 2nd instance?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Do you want something like `| sed -n 2p` ?

Comment: @WalterA no, as you never need a pipe to sed when you're using awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Yep. I wanted a short way to ask for better specs, the solution can be one `awk` without `sed` or `pr`.

Answer (score 0):

To only get the second instance of a string in awk, you'd want to use something like:

```
/CHEESE/ { seen_it++ } seen_it == 1
```

Example:

```
nick-chambers:~ nick.chambers$ printf 'line 1\nline CHEESE 2\nyou will CHEESE see me\nbut not me\n' | awk '/CHEESE/ { seen_it++ } seen_it == 1'
line CHEESE 2
```

If you still only want the fourth column, you can use:

```
/CHEESE/ { seen_it++ } seen_it == 1 { print $4 }
```

Comment: That would more typically be written as `'/CHEESE/ && ++cnt==2'` but in any case that'd just get the 2nd CHEESE from the first file rather than the 2nd CHEESE from every file which I **think** is what the OP might want. There are other issues too but we'll know more if/when they provide sample input/output.

Comment: Yeah, if they wanted to golf it that would certainly be better. I find the way I wrote it a bit more readable, but dealer's choice. I missed the multiple files, my bad.